# Joomla dropdown menu

Tags: php, html, css, joomla

I have a problem with dropdown bootstrap menu in joomla. It looks like it's expaneded all the time. I've already overwritten a mod_menu, so < li > have a class = "nav-item" and I think it can be cause of this problem. Maybe someone had a simillar problem, and know how to solve this. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZTTW.png)

The red element's should be visible only when i focus the 'dropdown menu', but they are visible all the time.

There is a html of the menu (Sorry for the style of  code)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md" id="navbar" style="background-color:#282d32;">
<div class="container-fluid">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="logo" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:25px;font-weight:500;letter-spacing:0px;font-family:'Noto Sans', sans-serif;"><strong>#</strong></a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navcol-1">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1" style="font-family:'Noto Sans', sans-serif;">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto" id="nav">
<li class="item-106 nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Main</a></li><li class="item-107 deeper parent nav-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link dropdown-toggle">Dropdown menu</a><ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto"><li class="item-108 nav-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item" style="color: red;">First</a>
</li><li class="item-115 nav-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item" style="color: red;">Second</a></li>
<li class="item-109 nav-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item" style="color: red;">Third</a></li>
<li class="item-110 nav-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Wywrotki</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="item-112 nav-item">
<a href="#" class="nav-link">xxx</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Edit: I forgot about fourth element in the menu, dont worry about this.

I would like to achieve something like 'hover me' on this page:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp

Comment: you'll get more help if you add the code you're workng with ( html and css at leat ) and what have you tried so far.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking help with code ("why is this code behaving like this?") should be accompanied by some code snippets, and include the desired behaviour. If you could, please add a minimal, verifyable, example showcasing your problem :)

Comment: Hello guys, thanks for advices, I did it allready

Answer (score 0):

the example in the link ( W3School ) is done with only css, but you `html` has `bootstrap` classes

so to make the dropdown work you need `bootstrap`'s `.js` and
here's a working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/69hev2g4/23/

basically you needed an `id` for the second `ul` and add `data-target` and `dropdown-collapse` to the link before , and the class `collapse` for it to be hidden at first,

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light" id="navbar" style="background-color:#282d32;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="logo" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:25px;font-weight:500;letter-spacing:0px;font-family:'Noto Sans', sans-serif;"><strong>#</strong></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navcol-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="" id="navcol-1" style="font-family:'Noto Sans', sans-serif;">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav " id="nav" >
                <li class="item-106 nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Main</a></li>
                <li class="item-107 deeper parent nav-item" style="width:284px;"><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dropdown"  class="navbar-toggler dropdown-toggle nav-link">Dropdown menu</a>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav collapse"id="dropdown">
                        <li class="item-108 nav-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item" style="color: red;">First</a></li>
                        <li class="item-115 nav-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item" style="color: red;">Second</a></li>
                        <li class="item-109 nav-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item" style="color: red;">Third</a></li>
                        <li class="item-110 nav-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Wywrotki</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="item-112 nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">xxx</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

you can use this tool to see the differences in code : https://www.diffchecker.com/